# Package Manager console ProjectItem.FileCodeModel returning null in VS 2015 but not in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget

There seems like there´s a bug in the Package Manager when using the ProjectItem.FileCodeModel Property in VS 2015, it returns null unlike VS 2013 where I get the expected object.

We´re using VS 2013 Ultimate Update 3 when this works and when using VS 2015 Enterprise Update 1 this returns null.

This is how to recreate the problem.

On VS 2013.

1. File --> New --> Project…
2. Choose Templates --> Visual C# --> Web. Pick the ASP.NET Web Application.
3. Choose the MVC template.
4. Open the Package Manager Console.
5. Insert this into the Package Manager Console: ((Get-Project).ProjectItems | ForEach-Object { $*.ProjectItems } | where { $*.Name -eq "RouteConfig.cs" }).FileCodeModel.CodeElements
6. This will return the CodeElements as expected.

On VS 2015.

1. File --> New --> Project…
2. Choose Templates --> Visual C# --> Web. Pick the ASP.NET Web Application.
3. Choose the MVC template.
4. Open the Package Manager Console.
5. Insert this into the Package Manager Console: ((Get-Project).ProjectItems | ForEach-Object { $*.ProjectItems } | where { $*.Name -eq "RouteConfig.cs" }).FileCodeModel.CodeElements
6. This will return nothing since the PM doesn´t find anything in FileCodeModel.

I´ve already reported this as a bug to Microsoft Connect (more details here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2313258), but I´m trying to find a temporary workaround for this or a solution.

I´m wondering if I´m doing something wrong in VS 2015 or if this is a bug? Is this happening to you as well?
Anyone that has any idea to what the problem might be? Feels odd that the organisation I´m working for is the first to ever have this problem...

Comment: I don't think this is related to VSO/VSTS, which is what #vso-package-management covers. You might want to tag this #nuget instead.